# Stripe Webhook JSON_DECODE not working (500)

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I'm having trouble getting stripe webhooks to work, this is my code:

```
            require_once('/var/www/html/application/views/config.php');

            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_***********");

            $input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
            $event_json = json_decode($input);

            //$event = \Stripe\Event::retrieve($event_json->id);
```

I've verified that $input is receiving the json data, but the $event_json variable is always empty.

I'm really confused by this, it seems like the json_decode is not working even though $input contains the correct data.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, for starters, stop suppressing the error messages for `file_get_contents` with the `@` character. I don't know why Stripe's docs suggest doing that. Are you sure you've got the API key right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The API key is 100% correct because the $input is receiving the JSON from stripe. Just seems to be the json_decode that is failing.

Comment: Try dumping out `$input` to see what's in it.

Comment: JSON data, just dumped it again to verify.

Comment: Does it validate on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ ? Can you share the value? Have you done `var_dump($event_json)` to confirm it's returning `null` as a failure?

Comment: The JSON validates fine on that site. The value of the JSON data? I've tried a var_dump on $event_json but it returns nothing.

Comment: A `var_dump` on a variable will always return *something*, even if it's just to output `NULL` or `bool(false)` or something like that.

Comment: To debug, I'm writing to a file to debug this. It's writing something to the file as it overwrites it so I think it's NULL. I could be wrong?

Comment: Am i having dejavu or this question was asked years ago.